# New-SShSession command not found in jenkins powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins

I'm using Windows Jenkins and installed the windows powershell plugin. from Jenkins I'm trying to connect to Linux instance and execute some commands in linux server.

```
> New-SshSession -ComputerName 10.0.0.xx -Username username-Password
> jenkins@123 Invoke-SshCommand -ComputerName 10.0.0.xx -Command "cd
> docker_CIServiceApp ; unzip prod.zip -d prod/"
```

But getting the error message from jenkins job as

> New-SshSession : The term 'New-SshSession' is not recognized as the
>   name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
>       operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
>       again.

The same command works in Windows Powershell terminal. What will be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for it might be that the Jenkins was started before SSH.NET plugin was installed. It modifies the environment variable and it requires process restart. Try restarting Jenkins process. Alternatively, it might be that the module is not loaded, try loading it first: `Import-Module SSH-Sessions`.

So, apparently you have installed a package in Visual Studio solution. Visual studio takes care of package download for you (`restoration`). It gets downloaded into `packages` folder under your solution. When you have no Visual Studio, like when using Jenkins and MS Build directly, you have to download package manually - get `nuget.exe` and run `nuget restore your_solution.sln`, this will then download the package under "\packages". Now you will have to import module, using the "\packages" path, probably.

Comment: I restarted the jenkins. But still getting same error in Jenkins job

Comment: SSH.NEt plugin and installed using Nuget.manually i imported the SSH-Sessions module and it works fine in powershell terminal. It fails only in Jenkins job

Comment: No.. when i try to import module through jenkins , i'm gettng error as no such module found

Comment: No i checked in internet , how to install SSH.Net plugin. They guided me to go through Visual Studio and Through Package Manager Console, install the SSH.NET. If it is wrong, kindly guide me how to proceed. I'm New to Powershell and jenkins integration

Comment: could you please explain briefly. Which solution i need to use? where to execute nuget restore command

Comment: Now i had got the packages and inside that i can able to view SSH.NET.2013.4.7 package. Now how can i import it in my jenkins job

Comment: You need to call `Import-Module` on it

Comment: You do `Get-Module –ListAvailable` and see all the details about your module, just pick yours and load it

Comment: It Works.. From jenkins i able to connect to Linux server, but it hangs after connecting to that server.. Unable to view the output

Comment: Can't help you with it, sorry. Just check that all of the mandatory parameters are passed and it doesn't prompt you for password, for instance

Answer (score 0):

your error indicates tha the module isn't installed:

```
PS /home/thufir/powershell> 
PS /home/thufir/powershell> Install-Module -Name SSHSessions

Untrusted repository
You are installing the modules from an untrusted repository. If you trust this 
repository, change its InstallationPolicy value by running the Set-PSRepository
 cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install the modules from 'PSGallery'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help 
(default is "N"):Yes
PS /home/thufir/powershell>
```